# How add images scrolling?

Tags: iphone, ios, image

I'm new in programming. How I can add small images scrolling and then when you click on one of them, it will be displayed on the main picture, with the ability to move and zoom in / out size? [Like this](http://s4.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2012/11/146bd3740e96e952fec493be9f97b5f7.png)

Advise some lessons, examples, tutorials or books please.

Comment: This site works in a QA format. What is your precise question and what have you tried? Broadly asking for suggestions is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this bellow examples and tutorial..

1. [HSImageSidebarView](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=hsimagesidebarview&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https://github.com/bjhomer/HSImageSidebarView&ei=oCa3UN60McjlrAf8u4DoCg&usg=AFQjCNHQB7REhfCym0yOitLdp5SQvbNrLg&cad=rja)
2. [iCarousel](http://haifa.baluyos.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=60%3aobjective-c-image-carousel-tutorial&catid=1%3aprogramming&Itemid=5) /// in this tutorial and demos many type of animations and style available for image slide show
3. [how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content)
4. [Three20 scrollview](https://github.com/facebook/three20)
5. [ScrollingMadness](https://github.com/andreyvit/ScrollingMadness)

i hope this help you..

Comment: @EdwardKorotaev hey see this demo dude.. https://github.com/bjhomer/HSImageSidebarView it is very useful to you..